# How can I log the activities of my android app on the phone seperated from any PC?

Tags: android, logging

I have created an app which so far works on my phone. But in order to check the long-term functionality I need to record the log file during a day or so, when the phone is not connected to any computer.

How can I do this?

Comment: That means you want to save logcat content for a day? Does your phone reboot in that day or does it connected to a charger? Can you use a computer before that day begins?

Comment: For that you'll want to save to a file in the external storage. And of course, every time you call `Log` also call the file code.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, I can connect the phone to a computer before I start logging. (AT) Budius: Do I have to overwrite my Log methods to write my logs to a file as well, or can I change my log settings somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Before you start testing, connect your device to a PC, open ADB shell and enter:

```
 logcat > /sdcard/mylog.txt &
```

That will dump logcat to file and will run in background, so it's continue to run even when you disconnect device from PC.

Comment: I will try later this day. How to stop it then? `logcat > /dev/null &`?

Comment: The easiest way is to reboot your device. Another way is to run ps command, find logcat process and use kill -9 command to shut it down.

Comment: Your suggestion kind of worked, but when checking the log I saw the it did not contain any time stamps! A log without time-stamp is not a log! The logcat in android-Studio contains the times.

Comment: The correct command is `logcat -v time > /sdcard/mylog.txt &`